# Get byte[] of a Drawable without Bitmap creation

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I need to send a PNG to a server. One very simple solution would be to create a `Bitmap` and convert it to a `byte[]` with the following code:

```
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.some_image);
final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
final byte[] data = os.toByteArray();
```

Since I want to save time and memory I would like to achieve this without the need of creating a Bitmap.

One idea would be to access the `Drawable` as a `File` but I don't know how to get the correct path.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did some testing on ``Resources.openRawResource(R.drawable.*)`` but didn't get constant results. Meaning the ``InputStream`` length didn't match the ones I can see on the file system. Anyway, this might give you means to read ``Drawable`` directly as ``InputStream`` and forward it to your ``OutputStream``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

harism gave me the final hint: use one of the `Resoureces.openRawResource` methods.

Here is my final solution:

```
private byte[] fetchImageData(Resources res) throws IOException {
    final AssetFileDescriptor raw = res.openRawResourceFd(R.drawable.some_image);
    final FileInputStream is = raw.createInputStream();

    // there are plenty of libraries around to achieve this with just one line...
    final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int nRead;
    final byte[] data = new byte[16384];

    while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
    }

    buffer.flush();

    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

In my case I had an PNG of 250x200 px and a file size of 42046 Byte. The `Bitmap` approach needs around 500ms and the raw approach 3ms.

Hope someone can use this solution.